# Python opens files before each file is finished being written to

Tags: python, file

I'm writing a program that converts the Dota format to the Yolo format (knowing the details of the formats is not important).

Many files need to be read from a directory (Dota files). Each line of every file is read and operated on. The output is a newly created file with the same name and the same amount of lines (minus the 2 lines used for metadata at the beginning of every Dota file which are removed) where the points are less than 1.

Example:

P0000.txt (Dota file, input)

```
imagesource:GoogleEarth                     //metadata
gsd:0.146343590398                          //metadata
2753 2408 2861 2385 2888 2468 2805 2502 plane 0
3445 3391 3484 3409 3478 3422 3437 3402 large-vehicle 0
3185 4158 3195 4161 3175 4204 3164 4199 large-vehicle 0
2870 4250 2916 4268 2912 4283 2866 4263 large-vehicle 0
630 1674 628 1666 640 1654 644 1666 small-vehicle 0
636 1713 633 1706 646 1698 650 1706 small-vehicle 0
717 76 726 78 722 95 714 90 small-vehicle 0
737 82 744 84 739 101 731 98 small-vehicle 0
```

P0000.txt (Yolo file, correct expected output)

```
0 0.7278709677419355 0.4441112322791712 0.03483870967741936 0.021264994547437296
0 0.8930322580645161 0.6191384950926936 0.012129032258064517 0.0056343147946201376
0 0.8205161290322581 0.7599054889131225 0.008 0.008360596146855689
0 0.7460645161290322 0.7754452926208651 0.012903225806451613 0.0059978189749182115
0 0.16412903225806452 0.3024354780079971 0.004129032258064516 0.0036350418029807343
0 0.1655483870967742 0.3099781897491821 0.004387096774193549 0.0027262813522355507
0 0.18580645161290324 0.015539803707742638 0.0030967741935483874 0.0034532897128316973
0 0.1903225806451613 0.016630316248636857 0.0033548387096774194 0.0034532897128316973
```

The problem is that the program works only with 1 file. If I put more than 1 input file in the dir, only the first output file is correct, the rest of the files have lines greater than their input file equivalent and some of the coordinates (numbers) are >1.

I think this happens because all input files in the directory are opened at once instead of 1 at a time where the equivalent output file has finished writing.

```py
textDir = "./inputData"
coordinatesList = list()

with open(textPath, "r") as f:
                    
    contents = f.read()
    contentsSplitLine = contents.splitlines()[2:]

    # print(contents)

    for i in range(len(contentsSplitLine)):
        splitLine = ' '.join(contentsSplitLine[i].rsplit(' ', 2)[:-2]).split()
        coordinatesList.append(splitLine)       

    imageHeight, imageWidth, channels = img.shape
    print(f"{imageWidth}x{imageHeight}")

    for coordinates in coordinatesList:

        coordinates = [eval(i) for i in coordinates]
        coordsX = coordinates[::2]  # get every other element starting from the first (x coordinates)
        coordsY = coordinates[1::2]  # get every other element starting from the second (y coordinates)

        minX = min(coordsX)
        maxX = max(coordsX)

        minY = min(coordsY)
        maxY = max(coordsY)
                        
        centerX = ((maxX + minX)/2) * (1/imageWidth)
        centerY = ((maxY + minY)/2) * (1/imageHeight)

        boundingWidth = (maxX - minX) * (1/imageWidth)
        boundingHeight = (maxY - minY) * (1/imageHeight)

        out = (f"0 {centerX} {centerY} {boundingWidth} {boundingHeight}\n")
        print(out)

        f = open(f"./outputData/{textFile[:-4]}.txt", "a")
        f.write(out)
        f.close()
else:
   continue
```

The rest of the [script](https://gist.github.com/HasanTheSyrian/7261e779d011fd57d080934cd8f2b9db) (incomplete)

Comment: textPath, textFile are not defined. What's with the `else` at the end? I don't see any corresponding `if`

Comment: they are, I didn't include them in the post, same with the encasing block that the else belongs to

Answer (score 0):

Clear `coordinatesList`

```py
...
if imageFile[:-4] == textFile[:-4]:

      imagePath = os.path.join(imageDir, imageFile)
      textPath = os.path.join(textDir, textFile)
      img = cv2.imread(imagePath) 

      coordinatesList = []
...
```